# Nodejs asynchronous function print data before execution fished

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using following NodeJS module for getting onvif device in the network https://github.com/futomi/node-onvif, and which works fine.

But using below code the list of device found is always empty. I checked the `getDeviceData` function and which is getting the device and print data.

But using below code the line  `console.log(JSON.stringify(list));` execute before all scan process completed. How can I fix it.

```
async function getDeviceData(info){
  var device = new onvif.OnvifDevice({
      xaddr: info.xaddrs[0],
      user : 'admin',
      pass : '123456'
    });
   await device.init();

  var dev_info = device.getInformation();
  var rtsp_url = device.getUdpStreamUrl();

   var data =   {"Manufacturer":dev_info.Manufacturer,"Model":dev_info.Model};
   console.log(data); // this print last
   return data;
}

const onvif = require('node-onvif');
onvif.startProbe().then((device_info_list) => {

      var list = [];
      device_info_list.forEach((info) => {
      var data = getDeviceData(info)  
      list.push(data);        
   
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(list)); // this print first

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:
You need to use `await` to wait the promise to resolve with the data.

```js
onvif.startProbe().then(async (device_info_list) => {

      var list = [];
      await Promise.all(device_info_list.map(async(info) => {
      var data = await getDeviceData(info)  
      list.push(data);        
   
  }));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(list)); // this print first

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: it's difficult to notice that the change you made is adding `await` before `getDeviceData(info)`, you should note it in the answer! (maybe even add a code comment next to it!)

Comment: I tried the code but got the error  `var data = await getDeviceData(info)  SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @CodeDezk wrap all the logic in this answer with an async function and call it, that should work.

Comment: I have wrap the above code in function `async function init(){...` and call` init();` still got same error.

Comment: @8HoLoN your answer is correct but lack explanations which is why I contracted the "upvote". If you decide to add explanations to the (good) answer you published, feel free to tag me here and I'll upvote it again.

Answer (score 1):

The data const in the first function returns a promise so would have yo await that. So this should work:

```
async function getDeviceData(info) {
  const device = new onvif.OnvifDevice({
    xaddr: info.xaddrs[0],
    user: 'admin',
    pass: '123456',
  });
  await device.init();

  const dev_info = device.getInformation();
  const rtsp_url = device.getUdpStreamUrl();

  const data = { Manufacturer: dev_info.Manufacturer, Model: dev_info.Model };
  await Promise.resolve(data);
  console.log(data); // this print last
  return data;
}

onvif
  .startProbe()
  .then(device_info_list => {
    const list = [];
    device_info_list.forEach(async info => {
      const data = await getDeviceData(info);
      await Promise.resolve(list.push(data));
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list)); // this print first
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```